# Searching for exact phrase

Tags: lucene

How do i achieve "Exact Phrase" functionality on this field using BooleanQuery/any other class? For example if a user types in "top selling book" then it should return books which has this phrase in its description.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the query within double quotes should work.